# Is there any unicode 6.x ready font?

Tags: fonts, unicode, truetype-fonts

I'm still looking for any TTF/OTF font with almost full Unicode 5.x or 6.x support, i.e. I'm interested in `Transport and Map Symbols` from Unicode [`6.2`](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/) range [`1F680-1F6FF`](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F680.pdf). Does this font exist at all?

The example of symbols: `⛍`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is technically impossible to cover about 100,000 characters when font techonology sets an upper limit of 65,536 glyphs.

To check out support to some specific characters in fonts, the best starting point is usually fileformat.info. Not perfect, but very useful. For example, its information about [support to U+1F680](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f680/index.htm) is that it is supported by the [Symbola](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/) font. (The LastResort font mentioned in the list is not a real font.) However, it is also supported by Segoe UI Symbol. (I found this out using [my simple IE-only utility](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/listfonts1.html) that checks the fonts in my computer.) It’s apparently shipped with Windows 7, but the [MS page about it](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1798) points to a purchase page that does not actually sell it.

Apart from font support, you may have other software issues. Many programs cannot handle characters past BMP (Unicode numbers 0 to FFFF hex.) at all, or require extra measures to deal with them; even typing them might be a problem.

Comment: yes, I'm using [fileformat.info](http://fileformat.info), but this site doesn't provide information like "this character is supported by FooBar font". I hope that font creators will add more symbols (ok, not all, they're limited) into their fonts but today I haven't any tool to find these "updated" fonts

Comment: Symbola is good, at this moment it partialy solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was using Windows 7 with "Segoe UI Symbol 5.01". However I found that starting
with version 5.90 [extra content](http://blog.quppa.net/2012/02/17/more-on-segoe-ui-in-windows-8) is added

```
Transport And Map Symbols: 70
```

the bad part is that version 5.90 and up are only available with Windows 8,
luckily I found [a tutorial](http://askvg.com/fix-unknown-characters-or-vertical-rectangles-are-showing-in-place-of-metro-icons-in-windows-8-start-screen-and-login-screen) that has it for download.